# Rails how to Render a form instead of redirect on submit?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that the results just show if render instead of redirect.

so the form must not be redirected. someone know if this is possible with rails?

the form is:

```
  Pac: <%= @pac %> 
                   Sedex: <%= @sedex %> 
                 <%= form_tag calculate_ship_path, :method => "get" do %>                          
                  <%= text_field_tag :post_code%>
```

```
                 <% end %>
```

the order controller and action is:

```
  def calculate_ship
    frete = Correios::Frete::Calculador.new cep_origem: "#{@order.seller.post_code}",
      :peso => "#{@order.product.weight}",
      :comprimento =>  "#{@order.product.weight}",
      :largura =>  "#{@order.product.weight}",
      :altura =>  "#{@order.product.weight}",
      cep_destino: params[:post_code]
    servicos = frete.calcular :sedex, :pac
    @pac = servicos[:pac].valor
    @sedex = servicos[:sedex].valor
    render '/path/to/rails/app//orders/:id/checkout'
  end
```

and the routes is:

```
get  '/path/to/rails/app//orders/:id/checkout', to: 'orders#checkout', as: :calculate_ship
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking to have the form submit and have the returned data displayed on the same page without reloading or going to a new page?

Comment: Hello @octopushugs, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has a very handy way to handle this: remote forms. The caveat here is that if you're not using Unobtrusive JS (UJS) then this won't work and you'll have to wire it up the hard way.

In form tag notation it would look something like this, presuming you're using Rails 5:

```
<%= form_tag(calculate_ship_path, remote: true, method: "GET") do %>
  <%# form stuff %>
<% end %>
```

You should be able to do this with most Rails versions, but it might look a little different. What this does, effectively, is submits your form via AJAX. You'll then be able to bind JS event listeners to `ajax:success` or `ajax:error` and handle the response you get from `calculate_ship`.

One thing to note is that when you're doing form submissions, the method is defaults to `POST`, and probably should be that, a `PUT`, or a `PATCH`.

Here's the related docs for rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-tag

Comment: They should be similar